# reshape or dcast long to wide with no value.var 2 columns

Tags: r, group-by, rename, dplyr, spread

I have a data.frame df with 2 columns, the first six rows are shown here but it has many more blocksequences, each spanning 3 rows:

```
blocksequenceid description
M049-S215-S085 ECDTM-49
M049-S215-S085 ICD-215 
M049-S215-S085 ICD-85
M049-S213-S044 ECDTM-49
M049-S213-S044 ICD-213
M049-S213-S044 ICD-44
```

I want to convert it to this format:

```
blocksequenceid description1 description2 description3 
M049-S215-S085 ECDTM-49 ICD-215 ICD-85
M049-S213-S044 ECDTM-49 ICD-213 ICD-44
```

I've thought about dcast and reshape but I don't know what to do when it says `ERROR: column time not found` for reshape and I'm not sure dcast is the right function to use here. This is what I've tried:

```
reshape(df, idvar='blocksequenceid', timevar = 'description', direction = 'wide')
reshape(df, idvar='blocksequenceid', v.names = 'description', direction = 'wide')
```

I'm sure this is so simple but there's just something I'm missing.

Comment: You can use `dcast` this way `dcast(blocksequenceid ~ description, data=df, value.var = "description")` but you have to set colnames manually, maybe using `paste0`

Comment: hmm I had tried that before and what it is doing is taking each description (of which there are many) and making a new column for each one, and then placing 0's under each new column. The message I get is `aggregation function missing: defaulting to length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the reproducible data.

```
t <- 'blocksequenceid description
M049-S215-S085 ECDTM-49
M049-S215-S085 ICD-215 
M049-S215-S085 ICD-85'

df <- read.table(text = t, header = T)
```

---

Here is a possible solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  rename(description1 = description) %>%
  mutate(description = row_number()) %>%
  spread(description, description1, sep = "")

#   blocksequenceid description1 description2 description3
# 1  M049-S215-S085     ECDTM-49      ICD-215       ICD-85
```

### Edit for modified data

```
t <- 'blocksequenceid description
M049-S215-S085 ECDTM-49
M049-S215-S085 ICD-215 
M049-S215-S085 ICD-85
M049-S213-S044 ECDTM-49
M049-S213-S044 ICD-213
M049-S213-S044 ICD-44'

df <- read.table(text = t, header = T)
```

In the updated data, you should do `group_by(blocksequenceid)` first.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  rename(description1 = description) %>%
  group_by(blocksequenceid) %>%
  mutate(description = row_number()) %>%
  spread(description, description1, sep = "")

# # A tibble: 2 x 4
# # Groups:   blocksequenceid [2]
#   blocksequenceid description1 description2 description3
#   <chr>           <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
# 1 M049-S213-S044  ECDTM-49     ICD-213      ICD-44      
# 2 M049-S215-S085  ECDTM-49     ICD-215      ICD-85
```

Comment: I'm getting error in rename(. , description=description1) : unused argument (description=description1) even though I am piping with %>% just like your example..

Comment: It should be `rename(description1 = description)` and not the other way around.

Comment: oh yea, no that's what I tried.. its still giving the same error

Comment: it was trying to use rename from plyr instead of dplyr.. dplyr::rename() fixed it. however now it can't find row_number()... and I can't seem to find the package that's from

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse)` instead as in my edit. `row_number` is from `dplyr`.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your help! It worked.. I'l make sure to include a reproducible data.frame next time :)

Comment: you can also try `as.data.frame(t(unstack(df,description~blocksequenceid)))` from base R